# In case M is small is it possible to recover the message

Tags: encryption, rsa

In the plain RSA encryption, suppose $N$ is 1024 bits and the public key $e = 17$. Is it secure to use this setting to encrypt very small message, say $3 \leq m \leq 9$? In other words, is it possible for the attacker to recover the message $m$ given the public key and the ciphertext $c = m^e \mod N$.

Answer (score 2):

No its not secure. As this is homework my hint is: Textbook (plain) RSA encryption is deterministic, and so encrypting the same message always gives the same...

Comment: Which also makes brute force a distinct possibility.

Comment: That nice answer works even without using that the given $e=17$ is small.

Answer (score 0):

No this it not even 'mathematically' secure, because for such small messages you have $m^e < N$ (and not only for $m\le 9$ but up to $m \approx 10^{18}$). And for these $c=m^e$ you can recover $m$ simply by computing the integer root $c^{1/17}$. This is easy because no modular roots are required, i.e. you can skip  the hard part RSA.